# extracting CSV data that needs to be re-read frequently?

Tags: variables, common-lisp, sbcl

Most of the time when I read in CSV data I use local variables:

```lisp
(defun do-something ()
...
  (let ((thing (read-csv #P"~/Desktop/file.csv")))

   .... do stuff with thing))
```

This works. However, some of my functions are becoming quite large and messy. So I tried putting the function to read in data in a special variable:

```lisp
(defparameter *file* (read-csv #P"~/Desktop/file.csv"))
```

But when I use the `*file*` variable, it doesn't update with the new file.csv.

Is there a way to force refresh or maybe a better way of extracting CSV data in real time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a variable, `*file*` is initialized from the result of `read-csv` function. So unless you `setf` `*file*` again from `read-csv` it will not update.

If the path doesn't change you could wrap `read-csv` into another function like:

```
(defun retrieve-csv-data ()
  (read-csv #P"~/Desktop/file.csv"))
```

And use that where ever you need the csv data.